# Why the object can`t be release?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a block retain cycle question.

1.Look at the demo,redView is a local var,just is kind of "UIView",when I pop secondVC,but secondVC and redView can`t be release. why?

```
@interface RedView : UIView
@property(nonatomic,copy) void (^redViewBlock)();
@end
```

---

```
@implementation SecondVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

RedView *redView = [[RedView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
 [redView setRedViewBlock:^{
    [self aSecondViewFunc];
 }];
[self.view addSubview:redView];

}

-(void)aSecondViewFunc
{
}
```

2.I add a greenView between secondVC and redView, greenView is a global var, when I pop secondVC,greenView and redView can`t be release,but secondVC can be release. why?

```
@interface SecondVC ()

@property(nonatomic,strong)GreenView *greenView;
@end

@implementation SecondVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.greenView = [[GreenView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 200, 200)];
  [self.view addSubview:self.greenView];
}
```

---

```
@implementation GreenView

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    RedView *redView = [[RedView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    [redView setRedViewBlock:^{
        [self justAFunc];
    }];
    [self addSubview:redView];

  }
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because redView has reference to SecondVC and SecondVC has reference to redView. You should do weakSelf:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
RedView *redView = [[RedView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 40, 40)];
 [redView setRedViewBlock:^{
    [weakSelf aSecondViewFunc];
 }];
[self.view addSubview:redView];
```

Comment: But redView is a local variable,  if redView does not added to SecondVC,it can be release.  So SecondVC reference redView is because that redView is Second`s subView?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter that it is "local variable". It exists in memory as subview of self.view (where self is your SecondVC) so is not released after exit of this block of code.